# Remove cross-reference to a footnote, but keep the footnote

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, footnotes

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

Where I can cross-reference a footnote without it showing up as a superscript. However, I don't want to change the behavior of `\footnote` globally, I just want to be able to get this behavior in a few places while maintaining the default behavior of `\footnote` everywhere else.

Here is a MWE of what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to footnote~\ref{fnt:1}\footnote{Here is a footnote\label{fnt:1}.}.

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

which is clearly not what I want. The problem is that I don't know how to make a footnote without generating an automatic superscripted cross-reference where it is created. Any ideas?

Comment: Could your question be generalized to: You don't want `\footnote` to print a superscript, but just a number? The result is that you'll still be able to reference it (using `\label`-`\ref`), but `\footnote` will always print a number on the baseline *in addition to* the actual footnote text in the footer area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `\footnotetext` and increase the counter manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to footnote~\ref{fnt:1}\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Here is a footnote\label{fnt:1}.}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing a superscript (via `\textsuperscript`), one can patch `\@footnotemark` to just print the number. The example below creates the option of using `\inlinefootnote` instead of `\footnote` to set either of the footnote styles.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=13\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\@inline@footnotemark\@footnotemark
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@inline@footnotemark}{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}{}{}
\newcommand{\inlinefootnote}[1]{{%
  \let\@footnotemark\@inline@footnotemark% Temporarily update \@footnotemark
  \footnote{#1}% Set regular footnote
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I want to refer\footnote{Here is a footnote.\label{fn:first}} to 
a footnote~\inlinefootnote{Here is another footnote.\label{fn:second}}.

See Footnotes~\ref{fn:first} and~\ref{fn:second}.

\end{document}
```

As can be seen, references still work as expected with either footnote styles.

Comment: This is great, except that I don't want to change the behavior globally. I just want to be able to do this in a couple of places, while maintaining the default footnote behavior everywhere else.

Comment: @okj: See my updated answer which provides `\inlinefootnote` as an option to switch to whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to footnote~\ref{fnt:1}%
\makebox[0pt]{\phantom{\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{Here is a footnote\label{fnt:1}.}.


\end{document}
```